# Disk space usage analysis tool for Alfresco (or CMIS)

Tags: gratis, disk-analysis, cmis

## Context

I have an Alfresco (documents repository) which is growing very big (terabytes) as more documents get added everyday, and I would like to know in what folders are the big documents, as a basis for decided what should be done (bigger disk? removals of unneeded documents? new policies about document upload?)

## Need

Is there a tool that allow one to get a good view of where space is used in Alfresco?
Maybe something like Baobab in Ubuntu filesystems:

[image: Ubuntu Baobab]

## Requirements

- Free
- Crawls the whole repository, no need to run actions for each folder
- No need to modify Alfresco server-side
- Bonus if compatible with any CMIS server, not just Alfresco
- Bonus for either graphical representation, or data that can be easily copy-pasted into a spreadsheet program.
- No problem if it takes a lot of time to calculate.

*Note: Alfresco stores files as blobs with a different structure, so usual file system analysis tools are not a solution.*

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with Alfresco in a long time (too complicated). Seems the development and community have come a long way since 2010.

What's wrong with Alfresco's own stuff, or an add-in? I was able to find the Repository Size Dashlet: https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/repository-size-dashlet does that meet your needs?

Screenshot: [image: Alfresco repository size dashlet]

Comment: +1 Better than nothing, but what I am looking for is size folder-by-folder, so that you can drill down and find that forgotten folder where someone has uploaded hundreds of VirtualBox images.